# Есть ли необходимость вызова Dispose у сокета после вызова Close

Tags: c#, .net, сеть, сокет

Есть ли необходимость вызова `Dispose` у сокета после вызова `Close`?

Использую `Socket` протоколом `Stream` *он же TCP* и протоколом `v4`.

И хотелось бы узнать можно ли клиента принудительно отключить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот вызов будет лишним. Если вы посмотрите [исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/net/Sockets/Socket.cs,1138) метода `Socket.Close`, то увидите, что внутри есть вызов `Dispose`:

```
public void Close()
{
    GlobalLog.Print("Socket#" + ValidationHelper.HashString(this) + "::Close() timeout = " + m_CloseTimeout);
    if (s_LoggingEnabled) Logging.Enter(Logging.Sockets, this, "Close", null);
    ((IDisposable)this).Dispose();
    if (s_LoggingEnabled) Logging.Exit(Logging.Sockets, this, "Close", null);
}
```

Comment: А что насчет принудительного разрыва соединения с клиентом?

Comment: @LLENN Что значит принудительного? `Close` не разрывает соединение?

Comment: `Close` для сервера разорвет все соединения, а для отдельного выбрать сокет и вызвать `Close`?

Comment: @LLENN Я не понимаю. Если у вас сервер, значит для каждого клиента есть отдельный сокет. Его закрываете, и все.

Comment: @LLENN, вы наверное имеете в виду команду по аналогии с `С` команду `shutdown()` - в `С#` этого не требуется,  метода `Close()` вполне достаточно.